# Is the matrix $A$ diagonalizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A$ is a complex $n \times n$ matrix such that $A^{k}=1$, for $k>1$. If $1$ is not an eigen value of $A$, then Will $A$ be always diagonalizable?

My try:
Since we have,
$$A^k-I=O$$ we have
$$(A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}+\cdots+I)(A-I)=O$$
But since $1$ is not an eigen value of $A$ we have $|A-I|\ne 0$, so we get
$$A^{k-1}+A^{k-2}+\cdots+I=0$$
So the $k-1$ eigen values of $A$ are given by $e^{i \frac{2 \pi q}{k}}$ ,where $1\leq q\leq k-1$
But how can i determine the geometric multiplicity nd algebraic multiplicity to take the decision whether the matrix is $A$ is diagonalizable or not?

Comment: You are working over $\mathbb{C}$ so you should say so. There is an almost trivial theorem: $A$ is diagonalisable if and only if $m_A(x)$ is a product of distinct linear factors. In this case $m_A(x)|x^k-1$ so must be a product of distinct linear factors.

Comment: Can i know where can i get the formal proof of your claim?

Comment: There's a proof here http://www.mathe2.uni-bayreuth.de/stoll/lecture-notes/LinearAlgebraII.pdf although I think there are easier proofs. The crucial lemma in the proof that "distinct lin factors implies diagonalisable" is this: if $p,q$ are coprime polynomials then $\ker p(A)q(A)=\ker p(A)\oplus\ker q(A)$, it's a simple application of the Chinese Remainder Theorem.